# DOMElement has no member named 'getFirstElementChild xercesc C++

Tags: c++, xml, xerces-c

I'm writing a xml parser file, called `GetConfig.cpp`. 
Here is my header file of 'GetConfig.h`:

```
#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMDocument.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMDocumentType.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMElement.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMImplementation.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMImplementationLS.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMNodeIterator.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMText.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMNode.hpp>

#include <xercesc/parsers/XercesDOMParser.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/XMLUni.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp>
```

However, When I try to compile the program, I get:

```
/home/pribeiro/sandbox/GetConfig.cpp:372: error: 'class xercesc_2_2::DOMElement' has no member named 'getFirstElementChild'
/home/pribeiro/sandbox/GetConfig.cpp:381: error: 'class xercesc_2_2::DOMElement' has no member named 'getFirstElementChild'
/home/pribeiro/sandbox/GetConfig.cpp:392: error: 'class xercesc_2_2::DOMElement' has no member named 'getFirstElementChild'
/home/pribeiro/sandbox/GetConfig.cpp:396: error: 'class xercesc_2_2::DOMElement' has no member named 'getNextElementSibling'
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting that ... 
In that declaration I use:

```
DOMElement *volume = dynamic_cast<xercesc::DOMElement*>
                                        (volManager);
while(volume){
    // to the parsing here
 volume = volume->getNextElementSibling();
}
```

I'm not sure ... Maybe something related to the version of `xercesc`? When I compiled that for `xercesc 3.1` it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Those functions were introduced in Xerces 3

You see them mentioned in the Xerces 3 API documentation:

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMElement.html

but not in the Xerces 2 API documentation:

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-2/classDOMElement.html

The string "getFirstElementChild" occurs 31 times in the Xerces 3.1.1 sources but not at all in the  Xerces 2.8.0 sources:

```
erik@ubuntu:/tmp$ file=http://archive.apache.org/dist/xerces/c/2/sources/xerces-c-src_2_8_0.tar.gz
erik@ubuntu:/tmp$ curl -s $file | tar xfz - -O | grep getFirstElementChild | wc -l
0
erik@ubuntu:/tmp$ file=http://archive.apache.org/dist/xerces/c/3/sources/xerces-c-3.1.1.tar.gz
erik@ubuntu:/tmp$ curl -s $file | tar xfz - -O | grep getFirstElementChild | wc -l
31
erik@ubuntu:/tmp$
```